# how to get list from a graph with AQL

Tags: arangodb

I have this path

```
(user)-[like]->(book)
```

Now I want to get a list of all books with all users that liked a book

```
USER          BOOK
[user, user]  book
[]            book
[user]        book
```

I have only found examples with a starting point but in this case there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that you have created a document collection `book` and `user` and a edge collection `like`:

```
FOR b IN book
  LET u = (FOR v IN 1 INBOUND b @@edgeCol RETURN v)
  RETURN { book: b, user : u }
```

The `@@edgeCol` is a [bind parameter](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/AQL/Fundamentals/BindParameters.html) and has to contain the name of your edge collection (in your case `like`).

This query should return you an array of documents with field `book` which includes your book document and an array `user` with all user documents who likes the book. If the query returns you an empty array of users for each book, you probably have to change the direction `INBOUND` in the query to `OUTBOUND` depending on the direction of your edges.

For more information about graph traversals in AQL you should take a look into the [docs](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/AQL/Graphs/Traversals.html).